# Is an app that does nothing but link to a web site functional enough to meet Apple's iOS guidelines?

Tags: web-applications, ios, appstore, app

I don't hang out on Programmers enough to know whether this question is "ok", so my apologies if not. I tried to make the title obvious so at least it can be closed quickly :-)

The question is simple. My employer wants "home screen presence" (or at least the possibility thereof) on iOS devices (also Android but I'm mostly interested in Apple at the moment). Our actual application will be a pure web-delivered mobile-friendly application, so what we want on the homescreen is basically something that just acts as a link to bring up Safari (or Chrome now I guess; not important). I'm presuming that that's more-or-less possible; if not then that would be interesting too.

I know that the Apple guidelines are such that low-functionality apps are generally rejected out of hand. There are a lot of existing apps that seem (to me) less functional than a link to something useful, but I'm not Apple of course.  Because this seems like a not-too-weird situation, I'm hoping that somebody knows it's either definitely OK (maybe because there are many such apps) or definitely not OK.

Note that I know about things like PhoneGap  and I don't want that, at least not at the moment.

Comment: Is my app allowed is a question best asked of those you are submitting your app too.

Comment: @Ryathal well yes of course, but my understanding from speaking with a number of iOS developers is that it's difficult to get responses from Apple before it's actually time to submit something. However I may be completely wrong, so if that's really the best thing to do in this specific case then I appreciate the response. (Make it an answer if you think it's "weighty" enough.)

Answer (score 3):

Probably not. See the [iOS App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> 2.12 Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps,  or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be
>   rejected

One might guess that if your app is just a pointer to a web site, not even the web site bundled into an app, then it's even less useful than the sort of thing contemplated in section 2.12.

Comment: OK thanks.  That's exactly what I was looking for; I'm not a registered developer and the version of the guidelines I have don't include the web site thing in that section.

Comment: isn't the Facebook app simply a website bundled to an app? or is the next rule `2.13 multi-billion dollar companies can have any type of app they want`

Comment: Why not register so that you can read the guidelines yourself? [It's free.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/register/)

Comment: I think that apps that are *implemented* (via PhoneGap or whatever) with web technologies are OK, so long as all (or most) content is actually packaged with the app (like the page templates etc, which is probably a good idea anyway).

Comment: @Caleb because somebody told me it costs money and I was too dumb to find out otherwise :-)  Thanks!

Comment: @Caleb ... well it's free to register but that particular document requires an "iOS Developer Program" membership, and that's not free.

Comment: @Ryathal *isn't the Facebook app...?* I guess you could look at it that way, but at this point I'd say that FB is really more like a service that has a number of interfaces -- it's not "just" a web site. Amazon and Google have apps that provide functionality similar to their web sites too, but I'd guess that most people don't think of them primarily as web sites. Where's the line between web site and service? That's for the people who write the rules to decide.